# Why Saitama doesn't want to unleash his full power?

Tags: one-punch-man

So far my impression of Saitama is him holding back his power.

Even when the "Strongest" Alien in the universe attacked him, he easily finished him with NORMAL punches. He hasn't unleash his full power and I'd like to know why.

Comment: Why would he if normal punches suffice? How would you even tell? It's one punch either way. Apart from that it's also a plot device to keep people watching of course.

Comment: He hasn't found any opponents that are worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saitama wants to find an opponent worthy of his power.

He commonly fights enemies, killing them with one-punch, hence the name. He has found that launching a full punch kills almost everything he face. There's no challenge in that.

So yes, he is pulling his punches. There will be multiple times where he can easily destroy his opponent, but does not "try" until it has shown to be strong enough.

**He is a hero for fun.** Not to save people, but to enjoy the thrill and be himself.

I've avoided spoilers the best I can, especially since I'm not sure how far you are.

Comment: remember you can hide spoilers with `>!` if they are relevant to the answer

Comment: He mentioned the "strongest alien" so I assume he's finished the anime. I don't think I did any spoilers though. Did I miss something? Feel free to edit for me!

Comment: i havnt seen it myself so i wouldn't know but just by reading the last line thought i'd just remind you of the spoiler block's existsnce incase if you didn't know about that

Comment: Ah. I appreciate the mention. I was saying that I don't believe anything to be a spoiler and that I didn't want to even include possible spoilers. And they shouldn't be necessary since most of the information is evident in the first episode. Thanks for looking out though!

Comment: the manga is still ongoing, though

Comment: The manga is slow :(

Comment: Also because his normal punches can split mountains *and* the clouds behind them. If he just goes around randomly using max-power punches on every enemy, there isn't going to be a lot of Earth left.

Answer (score -1):

Saitama is a one punch wonder so he often beats monsters with only One Punch so till now he is finding an opponent who is worthy of his caliber to bring out his 100% of his power until then he feels his normal punches would be used for best to kill any type of human or monster